# undefined local variable or method `current_order'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a new model named `PaypalOrder` using:

```
rails generate model order_id:integer ip_address:string first_name:string last_name:string card_type:string card_expires_on:date
```

Then I ran `rake db:migrate`

Now my order model looks like:

```
class PaypalOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification

  validate :validate_card, :on => :create

  def purchase
  #code
  end

  private
  def validate_card
  #code
  end

  def credit_card
  #code
  end

end
```

and the controller i created:

```
class PaypalOrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new
  end

  def create
    @paypal_order = current_order.build_paypal_order(params[:paypal_order])
    if @paypal_order.save
      # ...
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError in PaypalOrdersController#create

undefined local variable or method `current_order' for #<PaypalOrdersController:0xf7b0a34>
```

Why am I not able to access the current_order and how can I successfully build paypal_order

**EDIT:** made the following change:

```
class PaypalOrdersController < Spree::BaseController
```

works fine now!!

Comment: But what is current_order actually? You're not defining it anywhere!

Comment: @FabKremer : I want to be able to access the Order model's current object to read its attribute values. How can I do that in the `PaypalOrder` model

Answer (score 0):

Why not change line 8 of your controller to:

```
@paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new(params[:paypal_order])
```

?

If it is Rails 4 you'll have to do:

```
@paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new(params.require(:paypal_order).permit!)
```

Comment: that will not take care of paypal_order.order_id = order.id

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, `current_order` method does not exist.

You need to **create current_order method** first before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your intention with current_order was to reuse the order instantiated by the new action...

Since instance variables don't live through more than one request you need to instantiate the paypalorder again.

```
@paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new(params[:paypal_order])
enter code here
```